# Interface not get callback Android

Tags: android, interface

I write custom Volley Android in other class. But I get problem with this. This is my custom volley class :

```
public class CustomVolley {

    private Context _c;

    public OnCallbackResponse OnCallbackResponse;

    public interface OnCallbackResponse {
        void OnVolleyErrorResponse(String TAG, String response);
        void onVolleySuccessResponse(String TAG, String response);
    }

    public CustomVolley(Context c) {
        _c=c;
    }

    public RequestQueue Rest(int METHOD, String URL, final Map<String, String> jsonParams , final String TAG) {
        Log.v("URL "+TAG, URL);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(_c);
        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(METHOD, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.v("onVolleySuccessResponse URL "+TAG, response);
                        if (OnCallbackResponse != null) {
                            OnCallbackResponse.onVolleySuccessResponse(TAG, response);
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                String resp="error";
                if (response != null && response.data != null) {
                    resp = new String(response.data);
                }
                if (OnCallbackResponse != null) {
                    Log.v("OnVolleyErrorResponse URL "+TAG, resp);
                    OnCallbackResponse.OnVolleyErrorResponse(TAG, resp);
                }
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                return jsonParams;
            }
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return params;
            }
        };
        sr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                Variabel.MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS_NEWS,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        sr.setShouldCache(false);
        sr.setTag(TAG);
        queue.add(sr);
        return queue;
    }
}
```

And i call in my Activity like this :

```
public class GeneralBusinessActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CustomVolley.OnCallbackResponse {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
....

    context= getApplicationContext();
    customVolley = new CustomVolley(context);

    String url = "https://sds.com/api/search/detail/business?id_business=" + s_id_business + "&" + Variabel.app_key + "="
                + Variabel.value_app_key;
        queue_getDetailResultBusiness = customVolley.Rest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, "getDetailResultBusiness");

    }

    @Override
    public void OnVolleyErrorResponse(String TAG, String response) {
        Toast.makeText(GeneralBusinessActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onVolleySuccessResponse(String TAG, String response) {
        Toast.makeText(GeneralBusinessActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

But this is not get callback onError or onSuccess... so how to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to assign the object or it will remain null. You can add a setter in your CustomVolley class. E.g

```
  public void setOnCallbackResponse(OnCallbackResponse l) {
     OnCallbackResponse = l;
  }
```

and in your Activity do:

```
  customVolley.setOnCallbackResponse(this);
```

`this` as argument for `setOnCallbackResponse`, because `GeneralBusinessActivity` is implementing  the interface in your case

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
public CustomVolley(Context c)
{
       _c=c;
}
```

to this

```
 public CustomVolley(Context c)
 {
      _c=c;
      OnCallbackResponse = (OnCallbackResponse) c;
 }
```